# Reading fields in database into a string gets spaces I can't remove

Tags: string, vb6

I'm using an API from a company called Visma. And when I read from their database I need to allocate space in a string depending on how many maximum characters there can be in that field in order to read from it.

It's something like this:

```
dim CustomerName as string
CustomerName = Space(50)

AdkGetStr(pData, ADK_CUSTOMER_NAME, CustomerName, 50)
```

I have to specify how many characters I allow to be read and the problem is that if I read a bunch of customer names, almost all will not use the maximum number of characters allowed and I can't get rid of the excess of space.

I have tried to Trim and replace " " with "" but there was no result.

Then I tried put in a customer named "test" and I know the first 4 characters in this string are letters and the fifth(5) is a space I can't get rid of.

Then I did this test:

```
CustomerName = Mid$(CustomerName, 5, 1)
'reading the first space after my customername

templength = Len(temp)
'templength is 1
```

So one space after my customername and it is the length 1 but looks like this:

[image]

And I cant get my MsgBox to show. It looks like it's longer then len = 1 ... and it's not equal to a tab or empty or null? What the hell is it?

It's not possible for a string to be something unique, is it? So it has to be equal to something... And if I know what that is, I can remove the spaces from my string.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print AscW(CustomerName)` to peek first character code.

Comment: Debug.Print AscW(CustomerName) puts out: 0

Comment: does that mean null? or what is 0?

Comment: This is a null char (ASCII zero). It is generally used to terminate C-type strings. If you have a string containing just a null char, it is empty.

Comment: But when i try to compare it above in my picture it doesent seem to be just empty otherwise it would go in my if?

Comment: A simple `Replace(CustomerName, vbNullChar, vbNullString)` would be enough in your case. You can wrap it in `CleanString` function if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no way of getting the length of the string from the database, you will have to clean the string yourself by searching for the character's position:

```
Function CleanString(ByRef str As String) As String

    Dim posNullChar As Long
    posNullChar = InStr(1, str, vbNullChar)
    If posNullChar > 0 Then
         CleanString = Left$(str, posNullChar - 1)
    Else
         CleanString = str
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: yes i tried something similar and got it to work right now, but i think your approach is better i compared it to a string containing all letters and numbers xD but i think i still need the loop and check all characters individually because an customername can have a space in it like "Fishers Corp" but yea thank you so much :)